# vbscript: How to include search text of a Word table in selection ?

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I'm using these scripts for a 'search and replace' action in VBscript. Problem is that some of the search fields are in a table in the Word document. My selection doesn't seem to include the text in that table. How can I improve my scripts so that my selection does include that text and replaces in the table as well?

```
function sendLetterGeneric(letter, Vars1, Vars2)
    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = False
    oWord.Documents.Open letter
    Set objSelection = oWord.Selection
    call replaceText(objSelection, Vars1, Vars2)
    oWord.PrintOut
    oWord.activedocument.Saved = True
    oWord.activedocument.close
    oWord.Quit
end function

function replaceText(objSelection, Vars1, Vars2)
    Const wdReplaceAll = 2
    dim counter
    counter = 0
    for each var in Vars1
        objSelection.Find.Text = Vars1(counter)
        objSelection.Find.Forward = TRUE
        objSelection.Find.MatchWholeWord = TRUE
        objSelection.Find.Replacement.Text = Vars2(counter)
        objSelection.Find.Execute ,,,,,,,,,,wdReplaceAll
        counter = counter +1
    next
end function
```

Comment: Are you still struggling with this? In order to answer we'd need to know what Selection is. It appears you mean you want to search the entire document? Is any of the text that's not being searched in a Header/Footer or graphic object that has text wrap formatting?